# Reactor switchIfEmpty and verifing an execution

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor, java-10

I have a simple repository implementation like this.

```
@Repository
public interface PolicyRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Policy, String> {

    @Query("{ id: { $exists: true }}")
    Flux<Policy> findAllPaged(Pageable pageable);
    @Query("{ name: { $eq: ?0 }}")
    Mono<Policy> findByName(String name);
}
```

And A simple Action Method on a controller like this.

```
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> createPolicy(@Valid @RequestBody Policy policy) {
        //Use The Mongodb ID Generator
        policy.setId(ObjectId.get().toString());
        return policyRepository.findByName(policy.getName()).flatMap(policy1 -> {
            return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("A Policy with the same name as the policy you are trying to create" +
                    "already exists"));
  }).switchIfEmpty(
          policyRepository.save(policy).map(p2 ->{
                    eventPublisher.publish(Events.POLICY_CREATED, p2.getId());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Policy definition created successfully");
                }));
    }
```

What I was looking to achieve was return a bad request if there exists a policy with the same name as the one being inserted or do the save operation if the findByName method returns empty.

The strange behavior is that The following test fails because save is always called whether or not findByName returns data or not.

Here is the test

```
@Test
    void testCreateDuplicatePolicyShouldFail() {
        given(policyRepository.findByName(eq(policy.getName()))).willReturn(Mono.just(policy));
        given(policyRepository.save(any(Policy.class))).willReturn(Mono.just(policy));
        given(eventPublisher.publish(Events.POLICY_CREATED, policy.getId())).willReturn(Mono.just(0L));
        webTestClient.post().uri("/policies")
                .syncBody(policy)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isBadRequest();
        verify(policyRepository, times(1)).findByName(eq(policy.getName()));
        verify(policyRepository, times(0)).save(any(Policy.class));
        verify(eventPublisher, times(0)).publish(Events.POLICY_CREATED, policy.getId());
    }
```

And it fails with the following exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NeverWantedButInvoked: 
com.management.dashboard.repository.PolicyRepository#0 bean.save(
    <any com.management.core.model.Policy>
);
```

Please am I doing something wrong. Any pointer will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with that mock setup is that `save()` IS always invoked. The `Mono` returned by the real repository is lazy, so nothing happens until it is subscribed to. And the job of `switchIfEmpty` is to make said subscription *only if it received no `onNext` signal*.

The method call is just that, a method call. Nothing `switchIfEmpty` can do to prevent `save` from being executed in this form. It's as if you had something like `System.out.println(getMessage())`: `getMessage` is called whenever that whole line is executed ;)

In order to test, what you can do is use `reactor-test`'s `PublisherProbe` in the mock:

```
@Test
void testCreateDuplicatePolicyShouldFail() {

    //set up a probe to verify that the save Mono is never triggered
    PublisherProbe probe = PublisherProbe.of(Mono.just(policy));
    //now let the `save` return the probe:
    given(policyRepository.save(any(Policy.class))).willReturn(probe.mono());

    //rest of the mock and invocation is same
    given(policyRepository.findByName(eq(policy.getName()))).willReturn(Mono.just(policy));
    given(eventPublisher.publish(Events.POLICY_CREATED, policy.getId())).willReturn(Mono.just(0L));
    webTestClient.post().uri("/policies")
            .syncBody(policy)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isBadRequest();
    verify(policyRepository, times(1)).findByName(eq(policy.getName()));
    verify(eventPublisher, times(0)).publish(Events.POLICY_CREATED, policy.getId());

    //but we now actually expect the save() to be invoked, but the probe to be inert:
    verify(policyRepository, times(1)).save(any(Policy.class));
    probe.assertWasNotSubscribed();

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to explicit this point in reactor's documentation ? It's pretty important and could use some details.

Comment: I disagree that this belongs to the reactor documentation. this is pretty much standard java... `maybeDoSomething("example")` and `maybeDoSomething(produceString())` are the same, and in the second case `produceString()` is always called, whether or not `maybeDoSomething` uses the parameter... the lazy nature of Flux and Mono is repeated throughout the documentation

Answer (score 2):

Can you please confirm that in the test you are setting up an empty mono.

Can you please replace the below line:

```
given(policyRepository.findByName(eq(policy.getName()))).willReturn(Mono.just(policy));
```

With this line:

```
given(policyRepository.findByName(eq(policy.getName()))).willReturn(Mono.empty());
```

The switchIfEmpty operator is only called if the Stream is Empty. 
Moreover, you can enable log to trace the flow as well. This can be done by adding a log operator after switchIfEmpty. e.g.

```
 return policyRepository.findByName()
                        .switchIfEmpty()
                        .log();
```

Comment: Ok, will do that

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error and the solution for it was using the `Mono.defer(()->...)` inside the `.switchIfEmpty()` function, due switch if is expected to execute always without side effects according to this [medium](https://medium.com/@nikeshshetty/5-common-mistakes-of-webflux-novices-f8eda0cd6291) article.